# Insert folder hierarchy as IPTC tags

Tags: windows, image-processing, exif

I have a lot of pics sorted and organized in folders as

```
~2009/Gotham Trip/Selena's cam/
~2009/Gotham Trip/Jason's phone/
~2011/Work/Bludhaven Visit/Barbara's cam/
~2011/Work/Blüdhaven Visit/Tim's phone/
```

Is there a Windows software tool to insert the folder hierarchy as `IPTC` tags of images in bulk?

Batch processing of [IPTC tags can be done using IRFAN view](http://tng.lythgoes.net/wiki/index.php/Batch_updates_of_IPTC_tags_using_IrfanView). But I would like to get this done automatically.

For example I want all the pics in `~2011/Work/Blüdhaven Visit/Tim's phone/`
to have the tags `Work`;`Blüdhaven Visit`;`Tim's phone`.